# Why does my export in package.json does not work?

Tags: reactjs, package.json

I'm building a React components library, built with Vite and Rollup. I created shortcuts for the imports, so I'll just have to write `import { Component } from "library"`, and `import type { Type } from "library/types"`

I created three shortcuts: `.`, `./index.css` and `./types`. The first two work, but the third one does not. When I try to import from `library/types` I get this error:

```
Cannot find module 'library/types' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

But the CSS one or root one work well.

Where did I go wrong?

This is my `package.json`:

```
"exports": {
    ".": {
        "import": "./dist/library.es.js",
        "require": "./dist/library.umd.js",
        "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./types": {
        "import": "./dist/types.d.ts",
        "require": "./dist/types.d.ts",
        "types": "./dist/types.d.ts"
    },
    "./index.css": {
        "import": "./dist/index.css",
        "require": "./dist/index.css"
    }
}
```

And the folder structure:

```
|-package.json
|-src
|-dist
|   |-index.d.ts
|   |-lib.es.js
|   |-lib.umd.js
|   |-types.d.ts
|   |-index.css
```

The only time it's working is when I put the `types` folder at the root of the project (which I'd prefer to avoid).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: include a "types" field for the "./types" module as well

Comment: There is one, pointing to `./dist/types.d.ts`, but it's not working, still getting the error

Comment: The node spec says the 'types' field has to be first for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, this needed to be added at the end of the `package.json`:

```json
"exports": {
    ".": {
        "import": "./dist/library.es.js",
        "require": "./dist/library.umd.js",
        "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./index.css": {
        "import": "./dist/index.css",
        "require": "./dist/index.css"
    }
},
"typesVersions": {
    "*": {
        "types": [
            "./dist/lib/types.d.ts"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: using typesVersion is no longer the prefered solution since TS supports the "types" field directly in the exports section.  A few things:  the one under "." doesn't have the 'lib' subdir.  Is that intensional?  Also, the node spec says 'types' needs to be before the other conditions.  You have it last.